# AWS Glue - Field with Json structure in Redshift

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

Hi I am using AWS Glue to try and load data from a Json file in S3 into Redshift. I am using a Json crawler with path as $[*] and for some reason one of the fields (grade) is coming into the table with a Json structure:

[image]

Any ideas on how to make "grade" just display the value for the grade itself? Do I need to tweak the PySpark script for the job?

This is the script so far:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.sql.functions import current_date 
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame

## @params: [TempDir, JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['TempDir','JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)
## @type: DataSource
## @args: [database = "linkredshift", table_name = "uni3", transformation_ctx = "datasource0"]
## @return: datasource0
## @inputs: []
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "linkredshift", table_name = "uni3", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")
df=datasource0.toDF().withColumn('data_date',current_date())  
datasource0 = DynamicFrame.fromDF(df, glueContext, "datasource0")

## @type: ApplyMapping
## @args: [mapping = [("first_name", "string", "first_name", "string"), ("last_name", "string", "last_name", "string"), ("subject", "string", "subject", "string"), ("grade", "string", "grade", "string")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1"]
## @return: applymapping1
## @inputs: [frame = datasource0]
applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource0, mappings = [("first_name", "string", "first_name", "string"), ("last_name", "string", "last_name", "string"), ("subject", "string", "subject", "string"), ("grade", "string", "grade", "string"), ("data_date", "date", "data_date", "date")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")
## @type: SelectFields
## @args: [paths = ["subject", "grade", "last_name", "first_name"], transformation_ctx = "selectfields2"]
## @return: selectfields2
## @inputs: [frame = applymapping1]
selectfields2 = SelectFields.apply(frame = applymapping1, paths = ["subject", "grade", "last_name", "first_name", "data_date"], transformation_ctx = "selectfields2")
## @type: ResolveChoice
## @args: [choice = "MATCH_CATALOG", database = "linkredshift", table_name = "dev_public_students", transformation_ctx = "resolvechoice3"]
## @return: resolvechoice3
## @inputs: [frame = selectfields2]
resolvechoice3 = ResolveChoice.apply(frame = selectfields2, choice = "MATCH_CATALOG", database = "linkredshift", table_name = "dev_public_students", transformation_ctx = "resolvechoice3")
## @type: ResolveChoice
## @args: [choice = "make_cols", transformation_ctx = "resolvechoice4"]
## @return: resolvechoice4
## @inputs: [frame = resolvechoice3]
resolvechoice4 = ResolveChoice.apply(frame = resolvechoice3, choice = "make_cols", transformation_ctx = "resolvechoice4")
## @type: DataSink
## @args: [database = "linkredshift", table_name = "dev_public_students", redshift_tmp_dir = TempDir, transformation_ctx = "datasink5"]
## @return: datasink5
## @inputs: [frame = resolvechoice4]
datasink5 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(frame = resolvechoice4, database = "linkredshift", table_name = "dev_public_students", redshift_tmp_dir = args["TempDir"], transformation_ctx = "datasink5")
job.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the grade field can be either a string or an int, doing a resolvechoice with a cast on it is necessary to make it one or the other. Try to change your applymapping1 line to these two lines:

```
datasource0= datasource0.resolveChoice(specs=[("grade",'cast:int')])
applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource0, mappings = [("first_name", "string", "first_name", "string"), ("last_name", "string", "last_name", "string"), ("subject", "string", "subject", "string"), ("grade", "int", "grade", "int"), ("data_date", "date", "data_date", "date")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")
```

Note that this changes your grade field to type int (as that is what I am casting to in the resolveChoice, in order to use the values in int). Feel free to transform the grade field into a string instead later, but int seems a better choice.

See here for reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-samples-medicaid.html

Comment: For some reason when I replaced the applymapping1 with both lines above the data doesn't get loaded, I am left with an empty table and 2 grade columns: "grade" and "grade_int". Can you please confirm?

Comment: Oops this should be a project, not a cast. I updated the code.

Comment: Now I ran with "project" instead and all the other columns were loaded but grade. Also I am still getting 2 columns: "grade" and "grade_int". Can you please confirm? Thank you

Comment: Hmm, can you add a ```datasource0.printSchema()``` after the resolvechoice line and show me what is in the logs for the schema? Note I reverted to a cast in the solution as that should have worked, and I added an AWS link for some background.

Comment: Sure will do, running now!

Comment: This is the result with project: 

root |-- first_name: string |-- last_name: string |-- subject: string |-- grade: int |-- data_date: date

Comment: Running now with cast and will paste the log as soon as it finishes.

Comment: This is the result with cast: root |-- first_name: string |-- last_name: string |-- subject: string |-- grade: int |-- data_date: date

Comment: hmm neither of those have the grade_int you are talking about. I am a confused about where you are seeing that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234668/discussion-between-err-and-jonlegend).

Comment: I flipped the lines of code around and this field "grade_int" is now getting loaded, however the field "grade" is still empty. Somehow the job is creating this field "grade_int" and populating this field as opposed to "grade"?